# Find the limit of shared object

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, mxml

I have been trying to play around with shared object , I need to alert the user what i am going to save in shared object , but whenever i call flush() i cant get the current limit of storage i.e as of now 100 KB. is there any way to get the current limit of shared object for a particular domain ?

i even tried flush status , but flush status is created only after it shows up the security panel , i need to know the limit even before flush calls the security panel.

i need data just like this have the limit 
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html

Comment: FYI: In Flash 21 (and above) the size limit has been removed and now each domain only has an Allow or Deny option....

Comment: can we find out whether user allowed/denied data storage for this domain

Comment: Place your `.flush` in a try/catch as an `Error` will be thrown if the user has denied domain LSO access. You should check the version (`flash.system.Capabilities.version`) to determine if you might have a LSO size limitation unless you can force your users to use Flash/AIR 21+

Comment: i want to know whether the user have allowed/denied data storage for this domain EVEN BEFORE i call .flush , because i want to alert my user what information am going to store , i want my user to be aware that i am going to store these information.

Comment: Not possible, only after you make the `flush` call will you get a pending status returned, at that point you know that the user has the security dialog presented. Pre-warn the user with a dialog if that is your goal and do a flush. Next time if the LSO exists (since you can read it) do not present your warning dialog as you know you can write an LSO since one already exists

Comment: Thanks you very much , can you please compose an answer with all your comments so that i can chose your's as correct answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SharedObject.size` will return current [size](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#size) of data on disk.

You can't get current limit, but I'm 95% sure you do not need it. Instead you can use `SharedObject.flush(128*1000*1000)` to [request](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#flush%28%29) unlimited space once.

Comment: Hi , thanks for replying , as another user stated that now flash 21 is not supportiing end user to change size , can we find out whether user allowed/denied data storage for this domain .